# Rspec test fail Hartl tutorial Chap. 9.1 - fails on Edit User title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, railstutorial.org

I'm still stuck on Edit User Chapter 9.1.1 test, though I worked out the first set of error messages -- thanks to you guys for the help on that.
A new test failure error has arisen in the same location where I was, and I was encouraged to open up a new question. I'll put my updated code here.

I'm running this test: $ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb -e "edit page"
I just don't see where the error is coming from, after a ton of searching.
I had updated Capybara 2.0.0 also

```
Failures:

  1) User pages signup edit page 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', text: "Edit user") }
     Capybara::ExpectationNotMet:
       expected to find css "title" with text "Edit user" but there were no matches. Also found "",         which matched the selector but not all filters.
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:60:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.56475 seconds
3 examples, 1 failure
```

Here's the User Page spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_selector('h1',   text: user.name) }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
  end

  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',   text: 'Sign up') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign up')) }
  end

describe "signup" do

    before { visit signup_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      it "should not create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
      end


    describe "with valid information" do
      before do
        fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
        fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
        fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
        fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
      end

      it "should create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
      end

     describe "after saving the user" do
       before { click_button submit }
      it { should have_link('Sign out') }   
     end
      end
   end

      describe "edit" do
            let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
        before { visit edit_user_path(user) }

        describe "page" do
          it { should have_selector('h1',   text: "Update your profile") }
          it { should have_selector('title', text: "Edit user") }
          it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
        end

        describe "with invalid information" do
          before { click_button "Save changes" }

          it { should have_content('error') }
  end
  end
end
end
```

Here's my amended User Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

   def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Your App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'    
      end
    end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Also attached is the edit.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "Edit user") %>
<h1>Update your profile</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

      <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>

    <% gravatar_for @user %>
    <a href="http://gravatar.com/emails">change</a>
  </div>
```

here is the Authentication Spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do

  subject { page }

   describe "signin page" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',   text: 'Sign in') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign in')) }
    end

    describe "signin" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Sign in" }

    it { should have_selector('title',   text: 'Sign in') }
    it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid') }

     describe "after visiting another page" do
      before { click_link "Home" }

    it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }
  end
end


  describe "with valid information" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before do
          fill_in "Email", with: user.email
          fill_in "Password", with: user.password
          click_button "Sign in"
     end

    it { should have_selector('title',   text: user.name) }
    it { should have_link('Profile', href: user_path(user)) }
        #it { should have_link('Settings', href: edit_user_path(user)) }
    it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
    it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path)}


  describe "followed by signout" do
    before { click_link "Sign out" }
    it { should have_link('Sign in') }  
end
end 
end
end
```

And the Header html.erb file

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
        <%=link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav pull-right">
                <li><%= link_to "Home",   root_path %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Help",    help_path %></li>
                          <% if signed_in? %>   
                          <li><%= link_to "Users", users_path %></li>
    <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">"
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Account <b class="caret"></b>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li>
          <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  <% else %>                    

    <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li>
    <% end %>                   
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>  
</header>
```

Comment: Try `content_for :title {'Edit user'}`

Comment: <%= content_for(:title, "Edit user") %>  this line didn't change the error

Comment: Also header tag isn't closed, though maybe it's a snippet.

Comment: header tag is in the original. Thanks Michael.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have your describe block nesting wrong.

'User pages signup edit page '

This is showing that the edit page is nested in 'signup', it should be under User pages.

This may be causing the context to be wrong

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_selector('h1', text: user.name) }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
  end

  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1', text: 'Sign up') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign up')) }
  end

  describe "signup" do

    before { visit signup_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      it "should not create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
      end


      describe "with valid information" do
        before do
          fill_in "Name", with: "Example User"
          fill_in "Email", with: "user@example.com"
          fill_in "Password", with: "foobar"
          fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
        end

        it "should create a user" do
          expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
        end

        describe "after saving the user" do
          before { click_button submit }
          it { should have_link('Sign out') }
        end
      end
    end
  end


  describe "edit" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit edit_user_path(user) }

    describe "page" do
      it { should have_selector('h1', text: "Update your profile") }
      it { should have_selector('title', text: "Edit user") }
      it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
    end

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Save changes" }

      it { should have_content('error') }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @muttonlamb I'll look into it. Where do you recommend learning about nesting in Rails convention?

Comment: It's not so much about nesting in rails, it's about how test context is set up in RSpec.  The various levels of describe blocks set different contexts.  I've updated the answer to help - basically I think your do, ends are out of order

Comment: In order to nest Edit pages under user pages, do I need to change the indentation or move the describe section (last 16 lines or so) up? Do the blocks need to be placed in a different order? I'm trying to study hartl's code on github.

Comment: If you copy the code about, and compare with your initial posting, there is and end which closes off describe 'signup' prior to commencing describe 'edit', this is the only change

Comment: Unfortunately, I did add in the extra 'end' but it did not change the error :(  I certainly cleaned up the code though - thanks for the tips @muttonlamb

Comment: Ok, something that I do just to see what is actually being render is throw in a test I know will fail, but will show me the html in the RSpec output.  In the first line after `describe 'page'` put `page.html.should == ''`.  This will show you the full html of the page in the console.  From this you should be able to see if the test is actually failing or if the test isn't picking it up properly...